# 404 error with Jenkins and bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, http-status-code-404, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

When attempting to use the git plugin on jenkins to connect my bitbucket repository, i get the following error:

Failed to connect to repository : Failed to connect to https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git (status = 404)

and of course I just copy and paste the URL into jenkins, so all the information is filled in. I have seen where other people have the same problem, but I cannot seem to ever find a fix or understand what they are saying.

If I use GitHub, it works just fine, so I am 99% sure its not my end...

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me setting up SSH without a passphrase. Yes, it's not a good practice but I couldn't make it work any other way.

I followed this article: http://jenkinsheaven.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/using-jenkins-with-git-on-bitbucket.html